# How to use a C# object in custom HtmlHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, object, html-helper

I am trying to use replicate the syntax for most of the standard HtmlHelpers where an `object` is used to add Html attributes to a generated tag.

I would like to have something like:

```
<%: Html.MyCustomHelper("SomeValue", new { id="myID", @class="myClass" })%>
```

How do I access the keys of that new object so I can add attributes from the view?

Would this use reflection? I've heard that word thrown around a bit, but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in helper methods use `RouteValueDictionary` to convert the `object` into a dictionary. They also provide two overloads for accepting HTML attributes, one which accepts an `object`, and one which accepts an `IDictionary<string, object>`:

```
public static string MyCustomHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string someValue, object htmlAttributes)
{
    return htmlHelper.MyCustomHelper(someValue, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
}

public static string MyCustomHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string someValue, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    // Get attributes with htmlAttributes["name"]
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ability was created by Eilon Lipton on the MVC Team.  Details are here - and download the provided code to roll your own.

http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/09/24/using-c-3-0-anonymous-types-as-dictionaries.aspx